# Remove ActiveJob lines from production.log and split it in error.log and std.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, capistrano, sidekiq

I just landed in a project in rail that is using capistrano for deployment and sidekiq for asynchronous tasks. I understand that capistrano uses /current/log/production.log to log the rails app.

I manage to change the log level to Warning level but I'm still having Info lines for what I believe to be sidekiq logs with ActiveJob tag. How can I have control over this logger?

Also I wish to have more control in order to have the logger to write info+ into one file and warning+ to other file. I there a standard way for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

ActiveJob, like ActiveRecord, shares a logger from the base class -- e.g., ActiveRecord::Base.logger.  It's an accessor to which you can assign your own logger so I would consider creating an initializer (config/initializers/loggers.rb) with something like this:

```
log_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..', 'log', "activejob_#{Rails.env}.log")
ActiveJob::Base.logger = Logger.new(log_path)
```

If the messages are coming from Sidekiq than ActiveJob (quite likely) then replace ActiveJob::Base.logger with Sidekiq::Logging.logger

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your guess did not solve my problem but helped me to discard the ActiveJob as the logger. The problem was the sidekiq itself was writing the logs. I still didn't found a way to control the log level from the capistrano to the sidekiq but I manage to log the sidekiq in a different file. That solve the problem for now.

Comment: Check out the sidekiq logging information here:
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Logging